# Why this union type works this way?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I was working with some union types and found this pattern that I am not sure how it works.

Lets suppose we have a type like this:

```
type Person = { name?: string; age: number; gender: string };
type Name = { name: string };
type Comb = Person | Name;
```

Now, lets declare some variables of that type and see which ones show an error:

```
 const object1: Comb = { name: 'pedro' }; //No error, it is Name type
 const object2: Comb = { age: 3, gender: 'male' }; //No error, it is Person type
 const object3: Comb = { age: 3 }; //Error, it needs 'gender' to be type Person
 const object4: Comb = { age: 3, name: 'pedro' }; //No error??? Why??
```

Now the last one is the one I don't understand, It is not a Person because `gender` is required and is not present, it is also not a Name because it has properties that are not defined in Name type.

Why does it pass without adding the `gender` property? Or without removing the `age`? How does this work? The official docs don't address anything like this if am not mistaken.

Thanks

Comment: I think it's because the types are combined. It's not an "or" situation.

Comment: "*it is also not a `Name` because it has properties that are not defined in `Name` type*" - it's *more* than a `Name`, yes, but that doesn't matter, it's still a valid `Name`. See [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) and [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Comment: Excess property checks only kick in for specific situations, and (unfortunately in my opinion) they do not warn on properties that are mentioned in *some* member of a union.  See the answer to the linked question for more information.